# oracle sql : how do i Identify the products which are sold more via online than from the shops directly in the last 3 months?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please improve this query and help me find the solution for it.

orders table

[image: invoice table]

```
    select orders.item,
        case when orders.ordertype='shop' then 
             sum(invoice.quantity) else 0 end shop,
        case when orders.ordertype='online' then 
             sum(invoice.quantity) else 0 end onlinee
    from orders 
         join invoice on invoice.orderid=orders.orderid
    where orderdate>=sysdate-90 
    and 'online'<'shop'
    group by orders.item,orders.ordertype;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want a `having` clause.  But you also need to get the `group by` right:

```
select o.item,
       sum(case when o.ordertype = 'shop' then i.quantity else 0 end) as num_shop,
       sum(case when o.ordertype = 'online' then i.quantity else 0 end) as num_online
from orders o join
     invoice i
     on i.orderid o= o.orderid
where orderdate >= sysdate - 90 
group by o.item
having (sum(case when o.ordertype = 'shop' then i.quantity else 0 end) < 
        sum(case when o.ordertype = 'online' then i.quantity else 0 end)
       );
```

Comment: @kamalkumar please accept the answer as the correct answer if it solved your problem so the user is awarded with reputation points etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select orders.item, orders.ordertype
From orders 
join invoice 
on invoice.orderid=orders.orderid
Join
(
select
orders.item,
sum(decode(orders.ordertype, 'shop', invoice.quantity, 0)) shop,
sum(decode(orders.ordertype, 'online', invoice.quantity, 0)) onlinee
From orders 
join invoice 
on invoice.orderid=orders.orderid
where orderdate>=sysdate-90
group by orders.item
) agg 
on agg.item = orders.item
Where agg.onlinee > agg.shop
```

Comment: missing expression

Comment: @kamalkumar there was a trailing comma after onlinee

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 1

Comment: @kamalkumar yeah, I missed the from/join part of subquery... pheew it's difficult to write sql whithout having the data to try on